# 2665 - Invalid Date Error in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to complete an insert into statement but keep getting a "Invalid Date" error as a result.

**My create statement:**

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE Date_Table,
    NO FALLBACK ,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      customer_field,
      date_field DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      other_fields
     )
PRIMARY INDEX ( date_field );
```

**My insert statement:**

```
INSERT INTO Date_Table
select
  a.customer_field,
  a.CAST (date_field AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  a.other_fields
from a
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- Making the date_field null by `cast(null as date) as date_field`
- checking each date in the `date_field` against `sys_calendar.calendar` to make sure they're valid dates
- Checking the type by `SELECT TYPE (date_field) FROM date_table GROUP BY 1`, they all turn out to be the 'date' type

Any thoughts?

Comment: left join <your table a> to sys_calendar, using your <date_field> = calendar_date where <you table a>.<some field> is null.  That will tell you if you have some values that aren't valid dates.

Comment: What happens if you eliminate the INSERT and simply run the SELECT? What is the data type of the column in the source table?

Comment: @Andrew, that's what I tried in my second bullet.  Returns nothing

Comment: @RobPaller, the select works just fine.  Also, I can create a volatile table without any problem.  Just the insert isn't working.  The source table is DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',

Comment: If the source table matches the destination column definition, you shouldn't have to cast it explicitly to copy it to another table. Have you tried eliminating the explicit cast? Just noticed your syntax is "a.CAST()" did you mistakenly copy the table alias outside the CAST here or is that what you have in the actual SQL?

Comment: @RobPaller  I originally didn't have the cast in there, just thought I'd try it as a potential fix.  I see the error message even without the cast statement

Comment: Have you noticed the error in SQL `a.CAST (date_field AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'),`. This might also be a problem. Use `cast(a.date_field as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Answer (score 1):

When you created Date_Table , the datatype you specified is date. May be the datatype of `table a` is is `VARCHAR`, which is  not matching with `Date_Table`. That is the reason you are unable run `INSERT` statement. We can go for `CAST`.

```
INSERT INTO Date_Table
select
  a.customer_field,
  a.CAST (cast(date_field as varchar(8)) AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  a.other_fields
from a
```

Comment: `varchar(8)` will truncate the date, in this case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found out it had nothing to do with the content of the date-fields. In my case, the order of the '`create table`'-attributes and '`insert`'-attributes was not the same, which caused this error-statement.

So, example:

```
create multiset table database.table ,fallback ,
     no before journal,
     no after journal,
     checksum = default,
     default mergeblockratio
     ( 
      selection_dttm date,
      strategy_nm varchar(30) character set latin not casespecific
     );
```

and then the 2 attributes in the insert statement in different order:

```
insert into database.table
select 
    strategy_nm,
    selection_dttm
from source_table
```